# Typed Datatable Memory leak

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, datatable, typed

I have a typed datatable using typed datarow.
In my table, I define at the creation the different columns.
My table contains numerous dictionary of (type, list(of datarow)) that I use for Indexing. I'm NOT using an external datasource. It's all in memory, because my tool needs a really simple database but I didn't want to use an external database. 
Now, this datatable is a public variable define on all my application. The user can load data by loading files. To make it simple, the datarow are erased and new ones are loaded when the user load a file.
Problem is, the memory is never freed : Each time a user load a file, the memory consumption grows, and never goes down.
I tried a lot of things :

```
Datatable.rows.Clear
Datatable.acceptchanges '-> Doesn't work

Row.delete
row.acceptchange 'on each row 
'-> doesn't work

Datatable = nothing 
datatable = new typed datatable 
'-> doesn't work

Datatable.dispose
datatable = new typed datatable
'-> doesn't work
```

I even tried to replace the rows value by new values, instead of replacing all the datarow, but no luck.
Every time, I do Dictionnary.clear on all internal dictionnaries.
On my typed datarow, I tried to implement a custom delete to make all value = nothing. It doesn't work either.

I tried to put GC.collect() after emptying the table.

My datatable inherits from a datatablebase, which itself inherits from datatable (because I have multiple typed datatable, all using the same type datarow -> the columns can change, but the properties of the datarow test if they are part of the datatable before sending back a value.
The numbers of line can be between 0 and 150000 lines (depending on the file loaded).

What am I doing wrong here ? If the user change too many times the database, it finishes by having a "out of memory".

EDIT : I can't really show code because it's in multiple place, but basically :

```
'Addind a row :
DT.addrow({myarrayofvalue})
'For each dictionnary (let's say the dictionary already exists )
'dictionary are dictionary (of integer, list (of datarow))
'there is a special code which create the list if the key doesn't exists
dictionnary(row.columnX).Add(row)

'now, when reloading data (let's say dico is one of my dictionary)
dico.clear
DT.rows.clear
DT.LoadDatagain
```

I do more tests and I have see that if I just regenerate dictionary (clear them, then row by row, recreate them), there is also memory leak... But not as big as when I replace all the data.) Just dico.clear is not enough ?
It's like all the datarow I created (and deleted) where kept somewhere...

EDIT : OK, new test :

```
Private DT as new datatable
Sub test()
   DT.Readxml(myfile)
   DT.acceptchanges()
   DT.rows.clear()
   DT.Acceptchanges()
End sub
```

I run the sub test several time, and the memory is not freed. It increases and increases and increases...
This is a classic datatable, not a typed one (I defined the column elsewhere, but that's not the point... it's the same with a dataset)
I really don't get it...

Comment: Did you tried to achieve "out of memory" case?

Comment: Yes. The test was easy : I just loaded the same file several time, and it happened. Know that each time I load a file, the first step is to empty the table (the datarow, not the column) and the dictionnaries.

Comment: You should show the code which loading data from file.

Comment: That is just pseudo code, because the sub is pretty long and they are several. Plus, the file I use is not just xml, it's a format I created (to be able to save more information in it than just the rows)

Comment: Without seeing how you loading data from external resources(files) difficult to help. Because the can be not only in your "table", but it can be in the some temporary variable where you load file before saving it to the "table".

Comment: Hi. I really can't, BUT I made a test : I now load the datatable by "datatable.Readxml"... I still make a datatable.rows.clear before (followed by an acceptchanges). And the problem is still there. For information, I tried to replace my dictionary(of integer, list(of datarow)) by a dictionary(of integer, datarow())... same problem... I even try to replace the list of datarow by list of integer (corresponding to the indexes), and same problem...